Why are old files automatically stored with Git LFS without migration?
I recently started using Git LFS and followed the documentation, which states that only new files matching the tracked patterns will be stored with Git LFS. To include existing files, the documentation mentions using git lfs migrate.
Here’s what I did:
Installed Git LFS and tracked these pattern:
git lfs track "*.jpg"

Ran git add -A and noticed older files in the staging area.
Committed and pushed to the main repository.
When I checked GitHub, older files already in the repository were marked as 'Stored with Git LFS', even though I didn’t run git lfs migrate.
My understanding was that older files wouldn’t be affected unless migrated. So my question is:

How could older files already be stored with Git LFS if migration
wasn’t performed?
Is the documentation incorrect or am I misunderstanding how Git LFS
handles old files?

Thanks for any clarification!

GitHub may simply be misrepresenting historical commits as if current attributes applied.

Looks like older files were handled by Git LFS because they were staged and committed after the .gitattributes update.
Migration (git lfs migrate) is only required for files already committed in previous history. The behavior is normal according to the Git LFS documentation.
Link: CLICK

The older files were staged and commited before the .gitattributes update.
